# What natural conditions would make a permanent red sky?

Tags: science-based, atmosphere

What conditions (the more permanent, the better) would make for a red sky?

All the better, could we be creating those things?

For instance, the sky is presently blue because blue light travels farthest. What conditions would make red light more prominent?

Technically, a copper color would be acceptable too.